# NullPointerException in Java code

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning Java and OOPS from oracle's website.  I'm doing [this exercise](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-questions.html).

I'm getting a null pointer exception when I run this code. Can someone explain to me what I've done wrong?

**Card.java**

```
public class Card {
 public enum Suits {
    SPADE,
    CLUB,
    DIAMOND,
    HEART       
  }

 public enum Ranks {
    Ace,
    DEUCE,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE,
    SIX,
    SEVEN,
    EIGHT,
    NINE,
    TEN,
    JACK,
    QUEEN,
    KING    
  }

    public Ranks rank;
    public Suits suit;

    public Card(Card.Ranks rank,Card.Suits suit) {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }
}
```

**Deck.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {
    public ArrayList<Card> cards;
    private Card card;

    public Deck() {
        for(Card.Suits s: Card.Suits.values()) {
            for(Card.Ranks r:Card.Ranks.values()) {
                card=new Card(r,s);
                 cards.add(card);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DisplayCards.java**

```
public class DisplayCards {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Deck d=new Deck();
        for( Card c: d.cards) {
            System.out.println("Rank of the Card:"+c.rank.toString());
            System.out.println("Suit of the Card:"+c.suit.toString());  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try pasting the stack trace from the exception into the question. This is usually the best way to start diagnosing such a problem.

Comment: It might speed up things if you said exactly were you get this NPE. Removing empty lines wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I'm sorry for not putting up the exception.

Comment: Extremely silly of me to not being able to debug on my own. Thank you everyone for helping out so quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'm coming from more of a C# background, but it doesn't look like you initialized your ArrayList Cards. Try initializing it in the constructor with:

```
cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 8):

`public ArrayList<Card> cards;` is never initialized, use `public ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();`

Answer (score 4):

you did not create the new `ArrayList` for `cards`.

replace: `public ArrayList<Card> cards;` with `public ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();`

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the list as well:

```
cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```